CPU spike when moving objects, rendering is not affected
I am learning how to use blender 4.2 and import image sequence as scalar data, so it is a volume. The nodes I use is bioxel nodes for scientific visualization.
https://github.com/OmooLab/BioxelNodes
I tested on different computers, different file size (160MB to 1GB), whenever I move the object or do something such as resizing, the CPU will spike to almost 100% and make it very laggy. The speed of rendering in the render viewport works just fine. (I render with GPU).
If anyone can provide some tips or guidance that would be great.
Thank you!

This sounds like it might have far more to do with the add-on rather than Blender itself, probably that said transformations trigger a recalculation but insist it happen right away rather than waiting till the transformation completes or put it on a tick. Have you tried contacting the developers?

@TheLabCat Thank you, I am trying to talk to the author and waiting for his response. A following up question, the node imports my image sequence as a volume. The volume is a square block that contains my data, the actual object can be shown by thresholding the data to reveal, but how do I get the actual object out as an individual mesh or volume? The node provides a function called "pick mesh", which will isolate and copy the actual object out, after that, there is no more lag. I am guessing that there is too much small empty stuff in the original mesh space that consumes CPU.

I recommend you ask that as a separate question so you can attach proper details to it.

@TheLabCat ok sounds good! thank you!
